# How to use the Sanity Studio with a Custom backend?

Tags: sanity

We have a legacy app and would like to migrate to Sanity for the new editorial content, but want to keep the previous backend intact with the ability to edit it in Sanity. Curious if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: The sanity team has a slack channel to which you get invited to when creating an account. I'm trying to integrate Sanity with a Spring and Java back end. Will update this post if I find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Sanity studio is open source, so practically its not something which is impossible. I have never tried but would love to. The editor has a great design and could be a great alternative to the legacy CMS backends for content editors. Probably someone from the sanity team can provide with a much accurate answer or how complex is it gonna be.

Comment: Does not seem like the sanity team is active on here though.